'Call to a member function getFieldDefinition() on string' error when opening folders or data objects in Pimcore
When one of our Pimcore users clicks a folder or data object in the tree to open its detail view, the following error is generated:
Error: Call to a member function getFieldDefinition() on string in [...]/vendor/pimcore/pimcore/bundles/AdminBundle/Controller/Admin/DataObject/DataObjectHelperController.php:487
We can't reproduce the issue for other users so the issue seems user specific.
Running the bin/console pimcore:deployment:classes-rebuild command, clearing caches and (re-)running migrations don't seem to solve the issue.
What could be going wrong?

The issue seems to be related to grid view configurations stored for that specific user. Removing the grid view configs related to that user from the database manually solved the issue (ie, remove the rows in the gridconfigs table where ownerId is the id of the user encountering the issues, and related rows in gridconfig_favourites and gridconfig_shares).
We suspect the grid view config causing the issue referenced a model field that no longer exists, but didn't verify this, at least we're sure that deleting the grid config and all references to it from those tables solved the issue.
